# Verify (ir)reducibility of systems of polynomials arising from representation problems over polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, affine-varieties

Let $K$ be a field. Often, the problem of solving an equation over the polynomial ring $K[X]$ can be translated into solving a system of equations over $K$. For example, consider the following property a polynomial $f \in K[X]$ of degree $2m$ can have.

> There exist $f_1, f_2, f_3 \in K[X]$ of degree at most $m$ such that $f = f_1^2 + f_2^2 + f_3^2$.

Writing $f_j = \sum_{i=0}^m A_i^{(j)}X^i$ for each $j \in \lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$, the above property can be translated into the solvability over $K$ of a system of $2m+1$ equations in the $3m+3$ variables $(A_i^{(j)})_{i, j}$.

I am interested in whether this system is (absolutely) irreducible. That is, if we assume $K$ is algebraically closed, whether the equations defining this system generate a prime ideal of the polynomial ring in the variables $(A_i^{(j)})_{i, j}$. How could one approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There exists algorithms to decide whether an ideal of a polynomial ring is prime or not.

You can find one in Section 4.4. of ADAMS, LOUSTAUNAU, An introduction to Gröbner bases, Grad. Maths. Texts 3 .

The algorithm is described on p.244.

Comment: Does that work in practice on this problem? [Here is a SageMath program that generates the ideal for a given $f$.](https://bit.ly/2Sgyvoq). For $m>1$ `I.is_prime()` and `I.is_prime(algorithm='gtz')` take a loooooooong time.

Comment: Furthermore, I would hope that this problem is sufficiently well-structured that one could get a solid understanding for all values of $m$ at once.

Comment: The algorithm with Gröbner bases also seems to check irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ rather than over $\mathbb{C}$. This does give a difference (e.g. for the polynomial $f=X^2 + 2$ and two summands, one has reducibility over $\mathbb{C}$ and irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$).
Of course there *is* an algorithm which checks irreducibility over $\mathbb{C}$ given by effective quantifier elimination, but that would again not provide insight in the problem in a reasonable amount of time.